# Is invoking a constructor needed for initializing variables to default values?

Tags: java, initialization

I tried to go through almost every article here about variable initializations, but I still do not understand couple things about it. It is not clear for me if we HAVE TO call the constructor to initialize the instance variables to default values or it can happen without invoking the constructor? For example, convention is that every class written by us in Java is invoking a super class constructor in its constructor to "initialize variables" of super class. What does it exactly mean? Do we have to invoke a super class constructor to initialize instance variables of super class to default values? Or even without invokin super class constructor instance variables have an default values, and we are doing this to pass them the values described in constructor or given during the declaration? The second thing is, that we can initialize variables in couple ways, by not giving them a values (they will be set to default values), giving values in declaration, for example:

```
private int number = 10;
```

or specifing values in a constructor. It is clear for me, that we have to invoke the constructor to initialize variables to values specified in constructor but what about other 2 examples? Do we also have to invoke constructor to initialize instance variable to these values? Can someone also give me an order for creating this in simple words? I know that there are a lot of articles here about order of object instantiation and initialization and i have read them all, but I still do not understand a lot of things there.
And tell me if I am wrong, but what I understanded, the answer to question is that we have to invoke a super class constructor to initialize super class fields to their default values because in the other way there will be no point to making a call the super class constructors necessary if the instance variables of super class would be already initialized with default values without calling the constructor - because we wouldnt have to worry that our variables are uninitialized if they are - with default values.

@EDIT: To be clear, my main question was:
When instance variables are getting a default value? In the constructor or before the constructor? Do constructor have to be called to initialize the instance variables, or the default values are assigned even before the constructor call?

Comment: How do you think constructors are being called?

Comment: Please consider rewriting this question concisely, with a clear concise single  question, and code examples demonstrating what you're referring to, rather than a giant rambling wall of text.

Answer (score 2):

In an Object Oriented Programming Languages "Object" plays the Key role. So, initiating the object is must. I couldn't exactly get what you are asking.. I'm telling according to my knowledge.

You have to instantiate a class to use its fields & methods. For that you are assigning like this

```html
Class_Name object = new Class_Name();
```

no problem whether you are creating a default constructor in the invoking class it will creates a default one.

But, once you created a constructor with parameters you have to create a default constructor to initiate an Object like above.

You may assign values to variables in the class as you described & through parameterized constructors. Its best to write private modifier for initiating a variable (here comes Encapsulation Concept).

You can change the value of the instantiated variable through passing a parameter in constructor.

If you haven't put any values for your variables. Compiler will put a default value for that.
Have a look at this article
https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [JLS 4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is
>   used:
>
> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is
>   initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10.2):
>
> For type byte, the default value is zero, that is, the value of
>   (byte)0.
>
> For type short, the default value is zero, that is, the value of
>   (short)0.
>
> For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.
>
> For type long, the default value is zero, that is, 0L.
>
> For type float, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0f.
>
> For type double, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0d.
>
> For type char, the default value is the null character, that is,
>   '\u0000'.
>
> For type boolean, the default value is false.
>
> For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null.
>
> Each method parameter (§8.4.1) is initialized to the corresponding
>   argument value provided by the invoker of the method (§15.12).
>
> Each constructor parameter (§8.8.1) is initialized to the
>   corresponding argument value provided by a class instance creation
>   expression (§15.9) or explicit constructor invocation (§8.8.7).
>
> An exception parameter (§14.20) is initialized to the thrown object
>   representing the exception (§11.3, §14.18).
>
> A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value
>   before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment
>   (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite
>   assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment)).

So if your field is not being initialized anywhere before it is being used, the initial (or default) value would be `null` for object/reference types, `false` for primitive `boolean` type, or `0` for any other primitive types (`0` for `char` is `null` character).

If the field is initialized, then we need to look at the order.

```
private class A {
    protected int a = 2;

    public A() {
        System.out.println("Printing from constructor of A");
        printValues();
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void printValues() {
        System.out.println("a = " + a);
    }
}

private class B extends A {
    private int b = 3;
    private int c = initC();

    public B() {
        super();

        System.out.println("Printing from constructor of B");
        printValues();
        System.out.println();
    }

    @Override
    public void printValues() {
        super.printValues(); // Call parent implementation

        System.out.println("b = " + b);
        System.out.println("c = " + c);
    }

    private int initC() {
        System.out.println("Printing from initC()");
        printValues();
        System.out.println();

        return 4;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B();
    }
}
```

This generates:

```
Printing from constructor of A
a = 2
b = 0
c = 0

Printing from initC()
a = 2
b = 3
c = 0

Printing from constructor of B
a = 2
b = 3
c = 4
```

In the constructor of `A` (which is the parent class), `a` (which belongs to `A`) is already initialized with `2`. The other 2 fields remains un-initialized, returning values specified by JLS 4.12.5.

Then the constructor of `A` finishes and returns back to the constructor of `B` (the child class). You would have expected it to go to the `B` constructor part, but something else happened before that - `initC()` is being called. At this point, we can see that `b` has also been initialized, but `c` hasn't been initialized because `initC()` is supposed to return the value to initialize `c`.

Lastly, we see all the 3 fields being initialized.

So this is the order:

1. Most super class' fields are initialized first.
2. When returning from super class' constructor, the child class initializes its own fields.
3. Constructor continues to execute, which allows you to use the initialized values.

So initializing inline at field declaration allows you to be sure that the field has the value when you use it even at constructor, while initializing at constructor could only ensure the value is initialized *after* it exits the constructor (child class can be sure that it is initialized too).

Answer (score 1):

> When instance variables are getting a default value? In the constructor or before the constructor?

Before the constructor. If they got their default value *after* the constructor, then there would be no point setting them to a different value inside the constructor.

> Do constructor have to be called to initialize the instance variables, or the default values are assigned even before the constructor call?

It doesn't matter, the constructor is *always* called when you make a new instance. If you write a subclass that doesn't explicitly call its superclass's constructor, then the superclass's no-args constructor will be automatically called.

For instance, this:

```
class B extends A {
     public B() {}
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
class B extends A {
     public B() {
         super();
     }
}
```

If you don't call the superclass constructor explicitly, then your superclass's no-args constructor will be called. If no such constructor exists, then your code will not compile.

A constructor is *always* called.